# Angular test strings but except status in brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I need an help so basically there is master list(arrList) and selected list(selectedArr). I'm checking from the master list whos `id` and `name` matched from selected list and based on that I'm making checkbox checked.

```
 const formControls = this.arrList.map(
      (control) => { 
        if(this.payload) {
          let item = this.selectedArr.find(
            (d) => d.id == control.id && d.name == control.name
          );

          return new FormControl((item !== undefined));
      }
```

In master list we got normal array of objects with id, name field

```
{
    "id": "23711086",
    "name": "Test Propose Concept2 [P]"
}
```

, but selected list(selectedArr) along with `id` and `name`, `status(Inactive)` is appended in name so for example

```
{
    "id": "23711086",
    "name": "Test Propose Concept2 [P] (Inactive)"
}
```

So even if the status is `Inactive`, since name(partially) and id is same I want to make it check, basically
 `d.id == control.id && d.name == control.name` it should return `true`

Comment: I’d consider adapting the object to have a proper status key.

Comment: @MikeOne well, arrays I'm fetching from API, any solution u have for the above issue?

Comment: If you cannot change it at the source, parse the string on response and return a more useful object to your component?

Answer (score 0):

We can add `regex` and test for bracket split it, take the first part and check with
`control.name`

```
const formControls = this.arrList.map(
      (control) => { 
        if(this.payload) {
          let item = this.dataOwnerSelectedList.find((d) => {
            const dName = d.name.match(/[^()]+/g);
            if (dName) {
              return d.id == control.id && dName[0].trim() == control.name
            }
          });

          return new FormControl((item !== undefined));
      }
```

This is the solution I found